# EasyAdmin bundle: How to show data in a table depending on a role?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

If I have a table full of data, how do I let a ROLE_USER to see only his posted data, and for ROLE_ADMIN to see all the data from all the users?

So far I got this:

```
class DocumentController extends EasyAdminController {

protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{
    /**
     * @var QueryBuilder $qb
     */
    $qb = parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);

    if (method_exists($entityClass, 'getUser'))
    {
        $qb->andWhere('entity.user = :user');
        $qb->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());
    }
    return $qb;
}
```

This helps me to see my table data according to a user, but I cannot make it work using roles.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this code allows you if you are admin you will see all data but if you are user you will see only your posted data

```
     $roleUser = $this->getUser()->getRoles();

        $isAdmin = 0;

        foreach ($roleUser as $role)
        {
            if ($role=='ROLE_ADMIN')
            {
                $isAdmin = 1 ;
            }
        }
        if(!$isAdmin)
        {

            if (null === $dqlFilter) {
                $dqlFilter = sprintf('entity.user_id = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());


            } else {
                $dqlFilter .= sprintf(' AND entity.user_id = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());
            }
        }


        return parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);
```